# How to get the notification that a user has been successfully logged in?

Tags: blazor-client-side

When user is logged in, I'd like to fetch user's profile data so that I can display them throughout the application.

```
<CascadingValue Value="@UserProfile">
   <div class="content px-4">
     @Body
   </div>
</CascadingValue>
```

I'd like to be able to intercept a request so that I can check 1) the user is logged in and 2) the `UserProfile` object is set. If the user's logged in but the object is not set then I'll make a request to the API to get data.

Here's the portion of the App.razor code.

```
<Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                @if (!context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                }
            </NotAuthorized>
            <Authorizing>
            </Authorizing>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
    </Found>
```

`<Authorizing></Authorizing>` can be used for when the authentication process is going on. How do I know when the process is done and that the user's logged in, so that I can fetch user's profile.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is the [RemoteAuthenticatorView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.authentication.remoteauthenticatorview?view=aspnetcore-3.1) component on the `Authenticator.razor` page. This component exposes all sort of properties that covers so many scenarios, i.e. `OnLogInSucceeded`, `OnLogOutSucceeded`, `OnLogOutFailed`, and so forth.

In my case, I wanted to queries user's profile data as soon as the login succeeds so I can display which organization's he/she belongs to.

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView 
  AuthenticationState="RemoteAuthenticationState"
  OnLogInSucceeded="@RestoreAppState" //this is the event I was looking for
  Action="@Action" />
```

OnLoggInSucceeded is what I was looking for

```
public partial class Authentication
{
    [Inject] AppState AppState { get; set; }
    [Inject] HttpClient Http { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }

    public AppAuthenticationState RemoteAuthenticationState { get; set; } =
        new AppAuthenticationState();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (RemoteAuthenticationActions.IsAction(RemoteAuthenticationActions.LogIn, Action))
        {
            // Preserve the current order so that we don't loose it
            //RemoteAuthenticationState.Order = OrderState.Order;
        }
    }

    private async Task RestoreAppState()
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppState.RootInstitutionName))
        {
            try
            {
                var profileData = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<UserProfileData>("userprofiles");
                AppState.RootInstitutionName = profileData.RootInstitution.InstitutionName;
            }
            catch (AccessTokenNotAvailableException exception)
            {
                exception.Redirect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There's even a possibility to preserve data between operations, such login, logout. It was good to watch [Daniel Roth explaining security works in Blazor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxZTD0isAxQ).